# Textbox Bind() Default Value

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Is it possible to default this textbox to today's date, without using the codebehind, and retaining the Bind()?

```
<asp:FormView ...>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateInput" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateCol") %>'>
        ...
    </InserItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Comment: You mean if `DateCol` doesn't have any value then you want to show today's date by default but without using code behind ?

Comment: On insert, DateCol never has a value as the row does not yet exist.

Comment: Why don't you want to use code behind?

Answer (score 0):

Best approach could be making it in your DB side,

Like this

```
Select IdCol, 
       ISNULL(DateCol, GETDATE()) as DateCol,
       OtherCol
from yourTable
```

Here give your `DateCol` default date if it's `NULL`

Comment: This will only work for reading from the DB, he wants a default value when his FormView switches to Insert Mode

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
<asp:FormView ...>
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateInput" runat="server" Text=<%=DateTime.Now.ToString()%>>
    ...
</InserItemTemplate>
```

When you Bind, other columns in the FormView will bind as it should.